# Converting proximity from PIXEL distance to GEOmetric distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, proximity, pixel, units, cell-size

I used the Raster>Analysis>"Proximity (Raster distance)" tool in QGIS in order to create a raster of distances to a particular value in another raster. This is the same sort of thing someone might do for a proximity to mainland analysis... only I'm using it for proximity to something else (a bathymetric slope of more than 10 degrees).

[image: Proximity tool in QGIS]

When I run the Proximity tool with my slope raster as the input file, and "Dist unit" as GEO, I receive a warning that "Pixels not square, distances will be inaccurate." I think this makes sense, as I'm using EPSG:4326.

[image: Pixels not square warning]

Unfortunately for me, the distances are important, and they are far off reasonable values in my region of interest (though their relative magnitudes make sense, which is useful). If I use PIXEL as the "Dist unit" instead, I do not receive this warning, and the distance values for the generated raster make sense. But how do I generate a raster from this with values that represent geometric distances (in meters)?

[image: Resulting raster]

Comment: Have you considered reprojecting your raster to a projected coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

As @Luke suggests in his comment, one solution is to use the raster reprojection tool (Raster>Projections>Warp) to reproject the *input* raster prior to proximity analysis. In my instance, I reprojected the raster indicating the location of the feature of interest from EPSG:4326 to 3857. Then I ran the new raster through the proximity tool, using GEO as the "Dist units". Band values in the output raster are now in meters.